# Convert hex to int, little endian

Tags: calc, binary

I want to use Emacs to quickly convert hex to decimal.

If I type `M-: #x1234` (i.e. `0x12 0x34`), I get `4460` which (I think) means Emacs is interpreting it as big endian.

How might I convert hex to decimal as little endian, so that `#1234` is interpreted as `13330`?

Comment: The input `#x0001` has no relationship to the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of byte sequences. The leading zeros are just ignored.

Comment: I have no doubt I'm confusing myself.  It seems like endianness does matter.  If I consider `#1234` (i.e. `0x12 0x34`), Emacs returns `4460` which corresponds to big endian.  Little endian would be `13330`.

Comment: `#x1234` is just the hexadecimal number. It is not considered as sequence of bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#x1234` is just a hex number and not a byte-encoding. You can easily define a byte encoding yourself.
For an instance with the following my-byte-decode function:

```el
(defun my-byte-decode (list)
  "Decode hex number big-endian encoded as sequence of bytes in a list."
  (cl-reduce (lambda (hi lo) (+ (* #x100 hi) lo)) list))
```

You can decode a little endian encoded number `(#x34 #x12)` by `(my-byte-decode (nreverse '(#x34 #x12)))`.

For completeness the encoding function:

```el
(defun my-byte-encode (number)
  "Big-endian encode hex NUMBER.
See `my-byte-decode' for details on the encoding."
  (unless (integerp number)
    (user-error "Expected an integer"))
  (let (ret)
    (while (/= number 0)
      (setq ret (cons (mod number #x100) ret))
      (setq number (/ number #x100)))
    (or ret (list 0))))
```

Test: `(equal (my-byte-encode #x1234) '(#x12 #x34))` gives `t`.

You get little-ending encoding by wrapping the `my-byte-encode` into a `nreverse`:
`(equal (nreverse (my-byte-encode #x1234)) '(#x34 #x12))` gives `t`.

---

Now I address the new version of your question:

> How might I convert hex to decimal as little endian, so that #1234 is interpreted as 13330?

EDIT: We already discussed in the comments that the number `#x0001` is the same as `1`. so the word size encoded in the string `#x0001` through the leading zeros is inevitably lost when the Elisp interpreter reads the string and interprets it as a number.

If you know the word size in advance you can pad the read byte sequence with zeros:

```el
(defun my-fill-front (list size val)
  "If LIST is shorter than SIZE fill it at front.
Use a list with VAL for fitting the size."
  (let ((len (length list)))
    (if (< len size)
    (append (make-list (- size len) val)
        list)
      list)))
```

Now you have all the tools above. Just use the encoding function, pad it with zeros such that it has the right size, transform to little endian, and decode:

```el
(my-byte-decode (nreverse (my-fill-front (my-byte-encode #x1234) 2 0)))
```

The answer is `13330` as you wish.

Comment: There isn't enough information to do an endianness conversion. You don't know how many zeros to add to the left of the input. An endianness converter should take a basis size (you've hard-coded it to 256, ok, why not) and a number of digits (here you're assuming that the size is whatever causes the input not to have zeros on the left).

Comment: @Gilles I am aware of that one needs to know the word size. And I already tried to convince the OP about that. The OP changed the number in his question from `#x0001` to `#x1234` because of that. But, you are right, I should clarify the restrictions in the answer. Using bytes for the definition of endianness is [pretty much standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). I do not only take that from the wiki page but also from my own experience. I already had to fight issues with the endianness on work and encountered always byte encoded systems.

Comment: @Gilles I added a function for padding the generated list at the front to obtain the right word size. That should solve the problem.